# MySQL - Delete a row witha condintion

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, sql-delete

I got a zoo DB and I have to delete a row when a container does not have a animal inside it. I tryied this:

```
DELETE FROM container
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(NameAnimal), NameContainer 
FROM animal, container
WHERE container.CodContainer =
animal.CodContainer AND
animal.CodContainer =
container.CodContainer
GROUP BY container.CodContainer) = 0;`
```

And i got this error:

```
`Operand should contain 2 column(s)e`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your where clause. You are getting the count of NameAnimal and the NameContainer and checking if they are equal to 0. This cannot work as you are taking two columns and then seeing if they are equal to a single 0. I assume you probably want to delete the part of the select statement with NameContainer to fix your problem.

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting this message: "Table 'container' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separte source for data.". So  I tried to remove the container in the line FROM animal, container but it didn't delete anything, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using `NOT IN` and a small select :

```
DELETE FROM CONTAINER
WHERE CodContainer NOT IN (SELECT CodContainer FROM animal
GROUP BY CodContainer);
```